# How converting a char on a esp32 can crash it?

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller, esp32, platformio

i'm running into a problem understanding why my program is crashing while running on an esp32 processor and is causing it to repeatedly reset. I am working on a NODEMCU devkit version of the esp32. I am using PlatformIO and utilizing the esp32 version of the Arduino codebase.

In my program, I am making a debug class to replicate what Serial does, but over UDP to any device on the network listening. Basically all it does is check if Serial is connected and sends the print statements to it. Otherwise it sends the print statements over UDP.

To do this, I created a class from the Stream class like Serial has been. This means I needed to make functions that write calls are sent to. Calls where all data has been converted to uint8_t. To send the data to Serial though, I have to convert it to a type it accepts. Effectively, this is how a char character ends up being passed to Serial:

```
Serial.print((const char*)((const uint8_t *) '-'));
```

Now, this basically just converts a char around. The conversion to uint8_t is done before I get it, I'm simply converting it to something the Serial class will accept. What I get instead is my controller crashing and a panic and resetting. Now, yes, I can change this around fairly easily by trying to prevent a char from being printed, but I would rather understand what's going wrong here, If this is imploding, likely there are other landmines I haven't stepped on yet and this one has already set me back far enough as it is.

Can anyone explain why converting a char around causes a crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cast a `char`, `'-'`, into a pointer, making an address out of the the `char` value. It's the same as doing `reinterpret_cast<const char*>('-')` and, assuming ASCII, it's the same as providing the address `0x2d` to the `print` function which will then start reading from address `0x2d`, which is unlikely a valid address for your program, so you'll have undefined behavior.

If you have a `uint8_t something;` then do

```
Serial.print(static_cast<char>(something));
```

which will use the `Serial.print` overload taking a single `char`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I figuring it had to me something messing with memory. The problem I have is half of what's going on there is out of my control. In my regular code, I pass the '-" in and the Print class code takes it and converts it to unin8_t* and passes it back to me in the class I built. I can't send that to Serial to print though. I have to convert it to something it will accept. Doing a blanket conversion to const char* worked fine for most things, but obviously it doesn't work for char.

Comment: Converting anything into a `const char*` and passing it to `print` will make `print` read the memory from the supplied address and forward until it finds a `\0`.  That will not work well for most things.

Comment: Honestly, maybe just s bit more help. I understand what you're saying. It worked most of the time because it likely have converted strings before, which will have their own flags to tell the program to stop going through memory. The problem I have is the Print class, which my class is built on converts most things, numbers, strings, charts, to this one type. I guess their idea was that you would just send it on. I would have to imagine that this data gets read at some point, which means it will need to be converted. Would you have an idea on how to safely convert something like that?

Comment: @Jordan I think you're supposed to inherit from the `Print` class in order for your class to accept arguments to print like `Serial` does by overriding the `virtual` member functions `size_t write(uint8_t)` and `size_t write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size)`. That's all really. The `print`/`println` member functions are not `virtual`.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. This gave me a great smack against the forehead jolt to make me think things through more clearly. I did override those functions and even attempted to use them myself early on. Unfortunately I didn't pay close enough attention to the parameters. One has a unit8_t and the other has a const unit8_t* pointer. When I was trying it out early on I passed the pointer, but without the size, so it said it wouldn't accept it. I just went back to my functions, stripped out the conversions and passed them properly to the write methods. Now they work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jordan It's often a good idea to take a step back like that :-) You're weclome!